# How do you use a private variable in child classes?

Tags: java

i have a private variable in my main class, is it possible to use it in other classes without making it a protected variable?

Comment: By "child classes" do you mean _subclasses_? Or _nested classes_?

Comment: use getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private member variables are restricted to that class, however you can introduce setter and getter methods to access them. This is part of [encapsulation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm).

An example from the URL (tutorialspoint) above, we have 3 private values with setter and getter methods that retrieve or set the value as needed:

```
/* File name : EncapTest.java */
public class EncapTest {
   private String name;
   private String idNum;
   private int age;

   public int getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public String getIdNum() {
      return idNum;
   }

   public void setAge( int newAge) {
      age = newAge;
   }

   public void setName(String newName) {
      name = newName;
   }

   public void setIdNum( String newId) {
      idNum = newId;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. That's the point of `private` vs. `protected`. Details in [the Oracle Java member access tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), which also features this table:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|                  **Access Levels**                 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
| Modifier      | Class | Package | Subclass | World |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
| public        |   Y   |    Y    |    Y     |   Y   |
| protected     |   Y   |    Y    |    Y     |   N   |
| (no modifier) |   Y   |    Y    |    N     |   N   |
| private       |   Y   |    N    |    N     |   N   |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: Why not use getters and setters simply to provide access to the field?

Comment: @nullpointer - You can, but that's not accessing the private members. That's providing accessors for them, which is different.

Comment: But the *real* reason this answer isn't more in-depth is I was sure I'd find a perfect dupetarget for it, and this was largely to try to stave off the inevitable one-liner answers with a CW. Then I got sidetracked. :-D